# Distribution of deviances from logistic regression

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, deviance

I would like to know what is the theoretical distribution  of the vector of (signed) deviances $d_i$ from a logistic regression. Failing that, is there a way to to transform them unto approximately normally distributed r.v.?

My model for the data generating process is the simplest one, e.g.

$$y_i\sim\mathcal{B}(p_i)$$

where

$$p_i=\pmb x_i'\pmb\theta$$

and $\mathcal{B}$ is the Bernoulli distribution.

so in R code:

```
n<-1000
p<-5
x<-matrix(rnorm(n*(p-1)),nc=p-1);
y<-cbind(1,x)%*%rep(1,p)
y0<-1/(exp(-y)+1);
y0<-rbinom(n,1,y0)

fit<-glm(y0~x,family="binomial")
y<-residuals(fit,type="deviance")
qqnorm(y)
qqline(y)
```

Comment: Deviance residuals $\text{sign}(y_i−\hat{\mu}_i)\sqrt{d_i}$ are approximately normal, or at least as approximately normal as you're likely to get.

Comment: but even a casual look at them shows the gaussian is not a good fit. Is there any other parametric distribution that would be a good fit for the $d_i$?

Comment: Without seeing them? I've already answered the generic question to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Let me re-phrase the question a bit.

Comment: Actually, for bernoulli data, those are pretty good.

Comment: @Glen_b: maybe I'm missing something, but when I run the code above and look at the QQ plot it's not really a good fit. Than tail quantiles are a bit off too...

Comment: The distribution is going to depend (heavily) on $\theta$ and $x_i$. You can see this by replacing `rep(1,p)` by other values such as `rgamma(p,2)`. The distribution also depends on the MLE itself, which has no closed form. This makes theoretical study of the small-sample distribution daunting.

Comment: @user603 residuals from a model fitted to 0's and 1's is - in all but a fairly small set of circumstances - not going to be remotely normal looking, even with the best possible transformation. I really don't understand why you think it's important to have, but if you *must* have Gaussian residuals, take the ranks of the data, subtract 3/8, and divide by $n+\frac{1}{4}$, yielding a percentage point between 0 and 1. Then take the inverse normal cdf of the result. This is a monotonic transformation of the original data that will look beautifully normal. It will also be useless.

Comment: @Glen_b: yes, and thanks to whuber's comment it's also clear that whatever that distribution, it will depends on the $\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* your individual binomial denominators $n_i$ are sufficiently large, *then* the deviance residuals are approximately normally distributed. This is the basis of the common assumption that the residual deviance $D$ has a chi-square distribution with df equal to the residual df of the model. Basically, the theory underlying these results is asymptotic for $n_i \to \infty$.

However, if your $n_i$ are small, then the theory no longer holds. In particular, for *binary* data, the individual $n_i$s are all 1, and the residuals don't have a sensible distribution at all -- they'll just be two clusters, corresponding to $y = 0$ or $1$. In this case, diagnostics based on the residuals aren't very useful, unless you can aggregate your data somehow to make each $n_i$ large.

Comment: Thanks, that corresponds to my experience. Can you provide a quotable source for your comments? ('the theory underlying these results is assymptotic for $p_i\rightarrow\infty$')